# Spring QuerydslPredicate - exception handling for bad types

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

I didn't find any proper solution for this so maybe you can assist. Basically issue is ultra simple I want to do some kind of "better looking" error handling when using **QuerydslPredicate**

I have entity where ID is of Number format (on database side) - on entity level its private Long id.

And here come my problem while fetching everything in normal (expected scenarios like):

- /testEndpoint&pageSize=100&id=1
- /testEndpoint&pageSize=100&id=1123123

All work great. But when I enter non numeric value to id like id=randomTest I got NumberFormatException

```
    @GetMapping
public ApiResponsePage listTest(
        @RequestParam(defaultValue = "0") final Integer pageNo,
        @RequestParam(defaultValue = "10") final Integer pageSize,
        @RequestParam(defaultValue = "id") final String sortBy,
        @QuerydslPredicate(root = TestEntity.class) final Predicate predicate
) {

    final Page<TestEntity> all = testEntityRepo.findAll(predicate);
    return all;
}
```

Case is that this exception is thrown on parsing level so its not even reaching **testEntityRepo.findAll(predicate);**. Is there any way to handle such exceptions in more "elegant" way ? So I can put some custom message etc ?

Log:

> INFO 18388 --- [           main] d.v.s.a.s.e.DefaultExceptionReporter
> : GET /testEndpoint caused Failed to convert from type
> [java.lang.String] to type [@javax.persistence.Id java.lang.Long] for
> value 'testRandomValue'; nested exception is
> java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "testRandomValue"

Answer (score 0):

The one option is to make exceptionHandler:

```
@ExceptionHandler(ConversionFailedException.class)
public ResponseEntity conversionFailedException(ConversionFailedException ex) {
     return ResponseEntity
            .badRequest()
            .contentType(APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
            .body(createResponseBody(ex.getMessage()));
}
```

This is working, but its taking all errors of this type so if you have any other place where it appear it can be overhead